# How to use a JSON array DB column in EF queries to perform filtering

Tags: c#, sql, json, entity-framework-core

Given the 'Product' Table:

```
[Table("products")]
public class Product: BaseModel
{

    [Required]
    [Column("Title", TypeName = "varchar(40)")]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("Description", TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string _Tags { get; set; }      //<<<<<<< **Json Array**
    
    [NotMapped]
    public string[] Tags
    {
        get => _Tags == null ? Array.Empty<string>() : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[](_Tags);
        set => _Tags = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    }
}
```

And the 'Product scores' table:

```
[Table("product_scores")]
public class ProductScore: BaseModel
{

    [Required]
    [Column("TagId", TypeName = "varchar(30)")]
    [Display(Name = "TagId")]
    public string Tag { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("Score")]
    [Display(Name = "Score")]
    public long Score { get; set; }
}
```

And using DBContext from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, I'm trying to do the following operation from a ProductService business logic:

1. Retrieve all Products from the store that are not historized ( third table)
2. Sort the products list based on the AVERAGE sum of the 'Score' per 'Tag' list

Example:
Products:

| Title | Description | Tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T-Shirt | A beautiful T-Shirt | ["fashion","comic","pink"] |
| Jeans | Strong Jeans | ["fashion","strong"] |

Product Scores:

| TagId | Score |
| --- | --- |
| fashion | 15 |
| comic | -2 |
| pink | 4 |
| strong | 20 |

The math should be for the product "T-shirt" = (15 -2 + 4) / 3 =  5,66
for product "Jeans" = 15 + 20 = 35

Sorting by those value should retrieve list of products (DESC):

1. Jeans
2. T-Shirt

This is my starting point:

```
_dbContext.Products
          .Where(p => 
            !_dbContext.HistorizedProducts.Any(hp=> hp.ProductId == p.Id && hp.UserId == CurrentUserId) 
            && p.UserId != CurrentUserId
           ) //<<< HERE I SHOULD "APPEND" the JOIN and the FILTERING;
```

The requirements needs it to be done on the DB level since we're applying Pagination.
I'm pretty new to C# programming, any help is very welcome.

Comment: I'm afraid you will not be able to manipulate the JSON inside the database with EntityFramework. I know SQL server has some capabilities to manage JSON so maybe with a stored procedure ? Or make "Tags" a separated table, that would solve a lot of issue.

Comment: Making tags a separate table is not really fitting our data model, how would you approach the stored procedure?

Comment: @GianlucaVasaturo, it has been a while since you posted the query. We are also having same challenge and data looks very much similar. Were you able to find any solution using EF or SQL. If yes can you please post here.